# Missing argument for parameter 'user' in call SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Please help, it is driving me nuts. I have a constant in ProfileViewModel (let user: UserModel) The UserModel is Identifiable in UserModel file I also initiate the user: UserModel in ProfileViewModel.

In HomeView I added the (let profileVM: ProfileViewModel) constant This allows me to retrieve a
user profile image through "profileVM.user.profileImageURL.

In my MainView I load the HomeView() based on being logged in or not I am asked to pass the profileVM and user let constants within HomeView() giving me an error to run the App.

Please see my code:

MainView.Swift (this is where I am asked for the arguments)

```
    import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct MainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var authViewModel: AuthViewModel
    @AppStorage("current_status") var profileRegistered = false
    
        
    var body: some View {

        ZStack{
            
            if authViewModel.session != nil && authViewModel.profileRegistered == false {
                RegisterView()
            } else {
                
                HomeView()
            }
           
            if authViewModel.session == nil {
                
                NavigationView{
                    
                    Login()
                        .navigationBarHidden(true)
                        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                }
                
            }
    
            
            
            }
        }
    }
```

HomeView.swift (just the top)

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import Kingfisher


struct HomeView: View {
    @State var showProfile: Bool = false
    @State var userSearch: Bool = false
    @EnvironmentObject var authViewModel: AuthViewModel
    let profileVM: ProfileViewModel
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                //BUTTON TO SHOW FOLLOWER SCREEN AND FIND PEOPLE IN THE COMMUNITY
                Button(action: { self.userSearch.toggle() }) {
                    
                    Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle.badge.plus")
                        .font(.system(size: 30))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    
                }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $userSearch) {
                    UserSearch()}
                
                Spacer()
                //BUTTON TO OPEN UP PROFILE 
                Button(action: { self.showProfile.toggle() }) {
                    
                     KFImage(URL(string: profileVM.user.profileImageURL))
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 36, height: 36)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                    
                }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showProfile) {
                    MyProfileView()}
                
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .padding(.top, 15)
            
            Button(action: {
                // logging out...
               authViewModel.signOut()
                
            }, label: {
                Text("LogOut")
                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
            })
            
            Spacer()
    }
}

}



    
var body: some View {
```

ProfileViewModel.swift

```
    import SwiftUI

class ProfileViewModel: ObservableObject {
    // MARK: - @PROPERTIES
    //∆..............................
    @Published var isFollowed: Bool = false
    let user: UserModel
    //∆..............................
    
    // MARK: -∆ Initializer
    ///∆.................................
    init(user: UserModel) {
        self.user = user
        /// ∆ Will persist if following or not even when you close the app
        checkIfUserIsFollowed()
    }
    ///∆.................................
    
    ///∆ ........... Class Methods ...........
    
    // MARK: -∆  follow •••••••••
    func follow() -> Void {
        //∆..........
        /// ∆ The current user logged in ID
        guard let currentUid = FIREBASE_AUTH.currentUser?.uid else { return }
        let followingRef = COLLECTION_FOLLOWING_FIRESTORE.document(currentUid).collection("user-following")
        let followersRef = COLLECTION_FOLLOWERS_FIRESTORE.document(currentUid).collection("user-followers")
        
        /// ∆ Updates the following structure when following someone
        followingRef.document(user.id).setData([ : ]) { _ in
            //∆..........
            /// ∆ Updates the followers structure when following someone with the currentUid
            followersRef.document(currentUid).setData([ : ]) { _ in
                //∆..........
                self.isFollowed = true
                print("DEBUG: Followed: @\(self.user.lastname)...")
            }
        }
    }/// ∆ END OF: follow
    
    // MARK: -∆  unFollow •••••••••
    func unFollow() -> Void {
        //∆..........
        /// ∆ The current user logged in ID
        guard let currentUid = FIREBASE_AUTH.currentUser?.uid else { return }
        let followingRef = COLLECTION_FOLLOWING_FIRESTORE.document(currentUid).collection("user-following")
        let followersRef = COLLECTION_FOLLOWERS_FIRESTORE.document(currentUid).collection("user-followers")
        
        followingRef.document(user.id).delete { _ in
            //∆..........
            followersRef.document(currentUid).delete { _ in
                //∆..........
                self.isFollowed = false
                print("DEBUG: UnFollowed: @\(self.user.lastname)...")
            }
        }
    }/// ∆ END OF: unFollow
}
//∆.....................................................

extension ProfileViewModel {
    
    // MARK: -∆  checkIfUserIsFollowed •••••••••
    func checkIfUserIsFollowed() -> Void {
        //∆..........
        guard let currentUid = FIREBASE_AUTH.currentUser?.uid else { return }
        let followingRef = COLLECTION_FOLLOWING_FIRESTORE.document(currentUid).collection("user-following")
        
        followingRef.document(user.id).getDocument { snapShot, _ in
            //∆..........
            guard let isFollowed = snapShot?.exists else { return }
            self.isFollowed = isFollowed
        }
    }
}
```

UserModel.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct UserModel: Identifiable {
    // MARK: - ∆@PROPERTIES
    //∆..............................
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    let headline: String
    let profileImageURL: String
    let firstname: String
    let lastname: String
    let email: String
    let bio: String
    var isCurrentUser: Bool {
        Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == self.id
    }
    //∆..............................
    
    //∆.....................................................
    
    ///∆ ........... Initializer ...........
    init(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        typealias k = RegistrationKeys
        //∆..........
        id = dictionary[k.uidKey] as? String ?? ""
        headline = dictionary[k.headline] as? String ?? ""
        profileImageURL = dictionary[k.profileImageURLKey] as? String ?? ""
        firstname = dictionary[k.firstname] as? String ?? ""
        lastname = dictionary[k.lastname] as? String ?? ""
        email = dictionary[k.emailKey] as? String ?? ""
        bio = dictionary[k.bioKey] as? String ?? ""
    }
}
```

RegistrationKeys.swift

```
import Foundation

struct RegistrationKeys: Hashable {
    
    static let emailKey = "email"
    static let headline = "headline"
    static let firstname = "firstname"
    static let lastname = "lastname"
    static let profileImageURLKey = "profileImageURL"
    static let bioKey = "bio"
    static let uidKey = "uid"
}
```

Registration function that uses the UserModel data to store in Firebase

```
 // MARK: -∆  registerUser •••••••••
    func registerUser(firstname: String, lastname: String, headline: String, bio: String, profileImage: UIImage) -> Void {
        //∆..........
        // MARK: -∆ (1) Upload Image •••••••••
        guard let imageData = profileImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3) else { return }
        /// ∆ Unique identifier for the image being uploaded
        let filename = NSUUID().uuidString
        
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(filename)
        
        storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { _, error in
            //∆..........
            if let error = error {
                print("\nDEBUG: {!!!} [ERROR] Failed to upload image: \(error.localizedDescription) {!!!}")
                return
            }
            
            /// ∆ Should print out before user is created
            print("DEBUG: Successfully uploaded user photo...")
            
            /// ∆ Accessing the image `URL` &
            storageRef.downloadURL { url, _ in
                //∆..........
                guard let profileImageURL = url?.absoluteString else { return }
                                
                let uid = FIREBASE_AUTH.currentUser!.uid
                    
                    // MARK: -∆ (4) Creating our document dictionary with keys & values •••••••••
                    typealias k = RegistrationKeys
                let data: [String : String] = [
                        k.uidKey: uid,
                        k.headline : headline,
                        k.firstname : firstname,
                        k.lastname : lastname,
                        k.bioKey : bio,
                        k.profileImageURLKey : profileImageURL
                    ]
                
                self.uploadCollectionToFirestore(
                    data: data,
                    uid: uid,
                    firstname: firstname,
                    lastname: lastname,
                    headline: headline,
                    bio: bio)
                    
                withAnimation{self.profileRegistered = true}
                }// ∆ END createUser into firebase
            }// ∆ END storageRef.downloadURL
        
        
        
    }
    
    
    
}/// ∆ END OF: RegisterView  Class
    
    extension AuthViewModel {
        
        
    
    // MARK: -∆ ••••••••• registerUser •••••••••
    fileprivate func uploadCollectionToFirestore(data: [String : String], uid: String,
                                                 firstname: String, lastname: String, headline: String,
                                                 bio: String) {
        
        isLoading = true
        //∆..........
        COLLECTION_USERS_FIRESTORE.document(uid).setData(data) { (err) in
           
            if err != nil{
                self.isLoading = false
                return
            }

            print("DEBUG: Successfully signed up user\n")
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you passing the `ProfileViewModel` to the `HomeView`

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Andrew I have a "let profileVM: ProfileViewModel" nothing more

Comment: @pawello2222 - I have edit the question with the entire code

Comment: Wow three downvotes....Why? I just need some help to move forward...

Comment: I looked at this question earlier and didn't understand how you handle UserModel and now I see that you have removed ProfileViewModel as a property from HomeView which means your question makes no sense at all since that is what you are asking about. I haven't downvoted this question but you need to fix this or I will join the down voters. And explain how thew UserModel fits in to all this.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - you're right sorry I seemed to have removed the profileVM property (added now). The UserModel stores the user data in Firebase by the use of RegistrationKeys.  I have added the UserModel and RegistrationKeys that save the data into Firebase. 

Am I missing anything else that would help? Sorry, I am also using an example from Github to rebuild Twitter --> see https://github.com/JoseM111/SwiftUIFirebase_TwitterCloneApp

Answer (score 3):

HomeView as written demands a ProfileViewModel:

```
let profileVM: ProfileViewModel
```

MainView as written instantiates HomeView, but doesn't provide that object. Xcode is complaining, perhaps in an ambiguous way without a helpful autocomplete suggestion.

```
HomeView()
```

To create a ProfileViewModel, you must provide it a UserModel according to the init you have coded.

```
init(user: UserModel) {
        self.user = user
        /// ∆ Will persist if following or not even when you close the app
        checkIfUserIsFollowed()
    }
```

So, in MainView, you need to know how to make the correct UserModel or provide some sort of default case that will trigger some reaction.

Based on the comment in the code, you have a persistence service that will spit that user data out for you.

```
HomeView(profileVM: ProfileVM(user: userObjectFromPersistence)
```

Comment: A tip: as written, your views act smart. They should be dumb. By smart I mean your views (1) know what other view require to work (2) what those requirements require to work and (3) how to get those requirements. On a break sometime, look up composable architecture for Swift, in particular a factory pattern. In that pattern, a dumb factory object knows how to make other objects (e.g., view models). Another object passes the factory the dependencies (e.g., networking). Essential Developer has some YouTube videos that may help. Composability will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Hi @Ryan thank you so much for your detailed answered and tips, really appreciate it. However, the code does not seem to work as I receive an error stating "Cannot find 'userObjectFromPersistence' in scope" - any thoughts? (will for sure look into the video)

Comment: That's placeholder text for you to fill in. It wasn't clear from your code where to get that user information.

Comment: the user object comes from the UserModel as is shown in the profile view model with the let statement. However, if I add the user: UserModel() it asks me for the dictionary and it gives an error. Any thoughts on what to do?

Comment: If I add this "HomeView(profileVM: ProfileViewModel(user: UserModel(dictionary: [String : Any])))" ---- it returns an error saying Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any].Type' to expected argument type '[String : Any]'

Comment: An error like that means you're passing a Type and not an initialized object. You need () after the dictionary. If you want to pass an empty dictionary, you can just write [:]

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses @Ryan appreciate it! However, I added this line HomeView(profileVM: ProfileViewModel(user: UserModel(dictionary: [String : Any]()))) and it returns the follow error --> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FIRESTORE INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but following/dGWVK6wlQ9YuhZB2AYdUFczlYWG3/user-following has 3'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Could it be I need to create a collection in my Firestore database? Manually add following and followers?

Comment: It's probably asking for some sort of root JSON-decoded dictionary object. Take a break and revisit the tutorial / download the final repo and inspect how they pass the user's identity at this point.t

Comment: I have been at this for a week now without success....Maybe it's best to find a different example or try a different approach to pass user data. Thanks for your help though @Ryan but I think me just reviewing the repo again will likely to be a success. If you find a solution at some point please let me know.